# SCVMM Powershell limit max number JOBS

Tags: powershell, max, jobs

I'm using System Center Virtual Machine Manager (SCVMM) 2012 sp1, time to time I'll have to create a bulk of new Virtual machines, 100 or more..

SCVMM allows send multiple Jobs using "new-scvirtualmachine" that they runs in parallel, but if I launch all SCVMM fails because powershell limits... I've already increased those limits allowing more Powershell tasks.

But seems that SCVMM doesn't have an implicit limit about how many concurrent jobs can't it manage.

I'd like to have a simply way to launch all creation Jobs at once without worrying about the limit.
There is some SCVMM setting that could it be configured? Or I should search/create an Script that limits the number of tasks that I'm launching?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The limit of jobs is 10,000 at once:

[The SCVMM Virtual Machine Manager service may consume high memory or CPU utilization](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2009348/the-scvmm-virtual-machine-manager-service-may-consume-high-memory-or-c)

> The maximum number of running jobs that an SCVMM system should be able
>   to handle is around 10,000 and hitting this many running jobs at one
>   time would be an exceptionally rare occurrence. Should it occur,
>   however, it can have a severe impact on the performance of the SCVMM
>   engine.

It seems unlikely you are hitting this limit.  More likely some other resource is constraining you.

I know from writing an app that automates the management of VMs via SCVMM that the bottlenecks were mainly network (for BITS download of VM templates) and disks (removing many disks at once killed the SAN).  In the end, I had to write a custom scheduler (in C#) that limited the number of VMs that could be created/removed at once, while allowing an unlimited number of configuration tasks (not such an issue as these connect directly to the VM, not VMM).

Comment: My SCVMM is installed on a Virtual Machine, and for a low number of Virtual machine creations I had to increase WSMAN Powershell limits like: WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\microsoft.powershell\Quotas\MaxProcessesPerShell 50
WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxShellsPerUser 60   -- Virtual Machines are deployed from Templates located the SCVMM Library, and it uses BITs to transfer